# Responsive family tree with bootstrap and css

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Im using CSS3 Family Tree and Bootstrap 4 but it is not responsive.

so I want to make it have a fixed width and to be just static or a way to fix the responsive view while zooming or in mobiles. I saw some similar questions with no  working answers.

[For Desktop resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvL8j.png)

[For Mobile or lower resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTFz8.png)

```css
.tree ul {
 padding-top: 20px; position: relative;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
 float: right; text-align: center;
 list-style-type: none;
 position: relative;
 padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
 left: auto; right: 50%;
 border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
 display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
 border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
 border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
 border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #666;
 font-size: 13px;
 display: inline-block;
 
 border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
 background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
 border-color:  #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree" style="width:100%;">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/T/details/1">تجربة 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://localhost/T/details/2">تجربة 2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost/T/details/5">هالوو</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="http://localhost/T/details/8">مشاكس</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://localhost/T/details/13">bla bla</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost/T/details/6">هلا والله</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="http://localhost/T/details/10">admin</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="http://localhost/T/details/11">test</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="http://localhost/T/details/12">test in test</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="http://localhost/T/details/16">عضو جديد</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="http://localhost/T/details/14">تست</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="http://localhost/T/details/15">كان ي مكان</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost/T/details/3">تجربة 3</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost/T/details/7">ضضضض</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost/T/details/4">هلا</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost/T/details/17">مشاكس</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost/T/details/18">مشاكس</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost/T/details/19">مشاكس</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```